# Qt: Sharing GL objects between several QQuickFramebufferObject's - on which thread to create the shared GL objects?

Tags: multithreading, qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

I have several QQuickFramebufferObjects between which I want to share some GL objects (shaders and VBOs mainly). My initial plan was:

- Create a class `SharedGLData` to hold the shared object
- Instantiate this class on the stack in C++'s `main()`
- Pass a pointer the object to QML via `ctx->assignRootProperty` or something
- Pass the object as a property to the QML items of type `SharedGLData`
- Access the pointer from C++

But that means I'd be creating GL objects on the main thread and later access them on the render thread. I'm pretty sure that's forbidden, for example see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#thread-affinity) where it says:

> QOpenGLContext can be moved to a different thread with moveToThread(). Do not call makeCurrent() from a different thread than the one to which the QOpenGLContext object belongs.

**Is it ok to follow my initial plan or is there a way to create shared GL objects on the render thread?**

A possible hack would be to put the shared stuff into a singleton that gets initialized on first use, and make my first use be directly from the rendering code. But that's a hack.

Another idea is to call moveToThread on the QQFBO's GL context to move it to the main thread, instantiate `SharedGLData`, then move the GL context back to the render thread. But I don't have a pointer to the render thread...

**Clarification after the answer I got:** By "render thread" I mean the thread that Qt SceneGraph silently creates to do all the rendering. It's not a thread that I'm creating!

Answer (score 3):

If you want multiple threads sharing OpenGL objects,

- Create a `QOpenGLContext`.  Usually, the first one you create should be the one belonging to the window (which will actually draw to the screen).
- Create a second `QOpenGLContext`, but call `setShareContext` before calling `create`.

You now have two OpenGL contexts which share objects (shaders, VBOs, etc) and you can now use these contexts simultaneously from different threads.

But... this often not an ideal experience.  In many cases, using OpenGL simultaneously from different threads will be no faster than using it from one thread, or it will be slower, or it will be buggier.  You are at the mercy of the OpenGL implementation.

### A Different Way

It sounds like your goal is to load assets (shaders, textures, vertex data) in a background thread while your main thread continues to render.  There is a more straightforward way of doing this that does not involve creating multiple contexts at all.

Simply map OpenGL buffers into memory in the rendering thread, and then pass the pointer to the background loader thread.  The loader thread is free to write data into the buffer while the render thread continues to make OpenGL calls.  When the loader thread is done, it signals the main thread, which does the appropriate synchronization and calls `glTexImage2D` or whatever.  These days, you can even keep a single buffer persistently mapped, but the traditional two-buffer method also works quite well.

Under this scheme, your rendering thread does not have to do any IO, and your background thread does not have to make any OpenGL calls at all.

You can't use this to compile shaders in the background but c'est la vie.

Comment: "If you want multiple threads sharing OpenGL objects" - I don't necessary want that. That's just a means to an end. And my goal is not to load assets in a background thread. My goal is just to ensure some GL resources are initialized, and loaded only *once*, before they're used by a bunch of QQFBO items in a shared manner. Normally I'd init the GL resources in one of the methods I've reimplemented in my `QQFBO::Renderer` subclass - either in `render()`, in `synchronize()` or in the constructor. That way they'd be initialized on the render thread.

Comment: And it seems like you're confused about my use of threads. You think that I'm creating and managing the threads. I'm not - I don't even want multiple threads. But Qt insists on doing all scene graph rendering on a separate thread, called the *render thread* - [see here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#threaded-render-loop-threaded). And that render thread is distinct from the thread that `main()` works on.

Comment: And since I can't think of an elegant way to put the shared-resource-initialization code on the render thread, I do it in `main()` instead. But then I'm creating GL resources on one thread, and using them on another, which is prohibited. **That's the problem.** Your suggestion of using a separate GL context for the initialization would work, but it would mean suffering the speed-hit of creating a GL context for every QQFBO, which may be too slow for my needs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here then—why are you creating OpenGL resources in `main` anyway?  Why not just create them once, on the render thread?

Comment: Because qt doesn't let have a mechanism for me to put, on the render thread, code to be executed once before any rendering is done. The only code of mine that runs on the render thread is per-item (my reimplementations of `QQFBO::Renderer`'s methods and `QQFBO::createRenderer`), not called just once before all items.

Comment: Can't you just have an `isInitialized` flag or something like that?

Comment: I can and I already implemented this solution (every item's renderer calls `this->sharedGLData->ensureInitialized()` in its `synchronize()` method), but I consider it a hack so I wanted something better.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a hack to me.  Putting an OpenGL context on the main thread just so you can initialize some resources there sounds like a massive hack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132930/discussion-between-stefan-monov-and-dietrich-epp).

Comment: @StefanMonov: Seems like you left the chat room.